# The usage of lurk before you leap

Tags: expressions, word-usage

***Lurk before you leap.***

I know it means familiarize yourself with a discussion group before getting involved. My question is whether it can be used in any other context except online learning, forum or whatever related to the Internet?

Comment: Have you looked up the word "lurk", and do you understand its meaning?

Comment: The original proverb is [look before you leap](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/look-before-you-leap.html)

Comment: I see, I didn't know the original one. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please do not offer misleading advice if you are not familiar with the question.

Comment: @Kris asking the OP if they have looked up a word is pretty much standard advice around here.  Knowing the meaning of "to lurk" helps the OP understand why the phrase may not be appropriate for all situations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see, I didn't know that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"My question is whether it can be used in any other context except online learning, forum or whatever related to the Internet?"

It is part of what is called "netiquette" and not common parlance. As it has a specific meaning (which the OP has correctly noted), it can only be used in that sense, in the context of online behavior.

*[Lurk before you leap](https://web.archive.org/web/20170717031846/http://trojan.troy.edu/etiquette/netiquette.html)* (Troy University, Troy, AL)

> Familiarize yourself with a discussion group before becoming an active participant. By lurking you familiarize yourself with rules, mailing lists, and the kinds of topics being discussed.